# Figure out the order of a list of chars

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

English has 26 chars (a,b,c,d,...,z) and they have the order `b behind a`, `c behind b`, etc.

Suppose we have another language. In the language, we also have a number of chars. All chars have an order, just like chars in English.

However, we don't know the total order of all chars yet.

We are given a list of words, in each word, the chars are sorted already.

Please use data structure and algorithm to induct the total order of all chars.

for example,

we have chars `@`, `£`, `$`, `%`. We don't know the order of these in a language.

We are given a list of words

`£ %`
`@ %`
`$ @`
`£ $`

Then we can get the total order `£ $ @ %`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a directed graph of containing all characters as vertices.

Create an edge from each character to each character directly following that character in any word. For example, if you have a word `@ % ^`, you'd have edges `@ -> %` and `% -> ^`.

Run a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the graph to get the correct order.